# I am facing an Null pointer issue while calling the driver in the test class in my automation project. How do I fix this one?

Tags: selenium, testng

I am using testNG and selenium Web Driver and I am always facing the issue with passing the driver instance. Here, the BaseClass is used to have my driver setup and which has @BeforeSuite annotations to call before all the things. But when the Test Class is executing, the driver value is getting NULL and its throwing an error.

```
 public class BaseClass {

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setup() {

        System.out.println("Initializing the driver");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/vinoth/Git/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://my.yocoboard.com");
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() {

        System.out.println("Quiting Everything");
    }
```

The Above class is my Base Class where I have initiated my driver setup.

```
    public class FirstClassYoCo extends BaseClass {

    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;
    SoftAssert softAssert;

    @Test(priority = 1, groups = "function")
    public void validateCurrentWeek() {

        //driver.get("https://my.yocoboard.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("vinothselvam070@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("vnotbs01");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Sign In']")).click();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='onLoadSpinner']/img")));
    }
```

The above one is my test class but while executing the first line of the "FirstClassYoCo", It throwing an Null pointer exception. The following one is the error statement

```
Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.20 (c99e81631faa0b2a448e658c0dbd8311fb04ddbd-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#355}) on port 41085
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1613131336.877][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 88.
Feb 12, 2021 5:32:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Login to the application

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.yocotest.FirstClassYoCo.validateCurrentWeek(FirstClassYoCo.java:26)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Try

static WebDriver driver; in BaseClass and use driver = new ChromeDriver(); in before setup.

In test case dont use Webdriver driver.

Issue will be resolved but better to use thread driver which helps in parallel execution..
[TestNG: Parallel Execution: Only active window complete the test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66002639/testng-parallel-execution-only-active-window-complete-the-test/66029601#66029601)

Answer (score 0):

### in your BaseClass , there is no class variable webdriver. The variable is defined as local variable for the setup() method. So that is not available for the FirstClassYoCo class.

### Also it is not in a constructor.

```
 public class BaseClass {

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setup() {

        System.out.println("Initializing the driver");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/vinoth/Git/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://my.yocoboard.com");
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() {

        System.out.println("Quiting Everything");
    }
```

Solution is :

```
 public class BaseClass {
    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setup() {

        System.out.println("Initializing the driver");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/vinoth/Git/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://my.yocoboard.com");
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() {

        System.out.println("Quiting Everything");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for null pointer is your class variable `driver` is not initialized. In order to fix it move class variable `driver` in base class and initialized it. For example:

```
public class BaseClass {
   protected static WebDriver driver;
   
   @BeforeSuite
   public void setup() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://my.yocoboard.com");
    }
}
```

This approach of having driver class variable is not recommended. There are opensource frameworks available as [third party extensions to TestNG](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions) that provides driver management and other features with TestNG. You can start using any of one. I would recommend [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io) that provides driver management, assertion and verification, resource management, locator repository, detailed reporting and more.

Your test case may look like below by just extending base class from QAF.

```
public class FirstClassYoCo extends WebDriverTestCase {

    @Test(priority = 1, groups = "function")
    public void validateCurrentWeek() {

        getDriver().get("https://my.yocoboard.com");
        //getDriver() .findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("vinothselvam070@gmail.com");
        getDriver().findElement("id=email").sendKeys("vinothselvam070@gmail.com");                      
        getDriver().findElement("id=password").sendKeys("vnotbs01");
        getDriver().findElement("xpath=//span[text()='Sign In']")).click();
        getDriver().findElement("xpath=//div[@id='onLoadSpinner']/img")).waitForNotVisible();
    }
```